# Indefinite Count Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I'm trying to create a counter that indefinitely counts up from that moment I upload it. I used countUp.js to generate this:

```
var options = {
  useEasing: false,
  useGrouping: false,
  separator: ',',
  decimal: '.',
};
var demo = new CountUp('myTargetElement', 0, 100000000, 0, 100000000, options);
if (!demo.error) {
  demo.start();
} else {
  console.error(demo.error);
}
```

It counts up to 10000000 at a rate of 1 per second. I just need it to live somewhere/keep counting so I can pull the counter's current value at any time.
Any ideas?

Comment: > need it to live somewhere/keep counting  

Do you mean,  you want that each user visiting has the same counter ?

Comment: I need to be able to reference the count's current value. The counter has to tick up indefinitely in the background. The way it currently stands, it starts counting up from 0 upon entry. I need it to keep on counting.

Comment: It seems your use case and the functionality of the library you've chosen don't really match up. If you're basing the count off a date, why not set up a simple interval that does a diff comparing the time of upload and current client time?

Comment: What I'm working with requires time to be displayed as single number in seconds. The starting point is somewhere around 15,000,000 seconds. I want to be create a counter that continues to add seconds to that value in real time. I know this is crazy backwards, I'm stuck with what I have.

Comment: Just saying, but "around 15,000,000" seems to be the current unix timestamp. I think you are trying to create something existent which is `date()`